# JQuery doesn't work with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple form in html5 with Bootstrap, but my JQuery doesn't work correctly, i'm trying with simply alerts without responses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Index Tecatche</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Email</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txt_email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txt_pass" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
 <input type="button" id="btn_enter" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enter">
 <input type="button" id="btn_register" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
 </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn_enter").click(function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: Is that the entire JS in `index.js`? Have you used the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors? Is the path to jQuery _really_ `…/3.3.1 /jquery.min.js` and not `…/3.3.1/jquery.min.js` without the space?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console?

Comment: The browser console don't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Js Code needs to Put in the ready().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn_enter").click(function() {
      alert("hi");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a space in your jquery path after 3.3.1  ..

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1 /jquery.min.js"></script>
```

change it to this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Alright** now you fixed the jquery path, does it still not work?

I have made a snippet below that uses the same code in your question (the only difference is i used a CDN for bootstrap.js). It seems to work fine when I run it.

---

Try wrap the event listener in a document  ready function. I have updated the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn_enter").click(function() {
      alert("hi");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Index Tecatche</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Email</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txt_email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txt_pass" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
 <input type="button" id="btn_enter" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enter">
 <input type="button" id="btn_register" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh! i didn't see that before post, but i have correctly that line.

Comment: i changed that, but i have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was missing that.

Answer (score 0):

just put your script after body tag and try to not include the index.js in your following libraries

and try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn_enter").click(function() {
      alert("hi");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Index Tecatche</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Email</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txt_email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txt_pass" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
 <input type="button" id="btn_enter" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enter">
 <input type="button" id="btn_register" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
 </body>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
</html>
```